# Fill Entire View of Page with CSS/Flexbox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Height still confuses me and when and where to put it.

https://jsfiddle.net/3pxmm0mz/

```
<div id="app"> 
     <div className="wrapper">
        <header>Header</header>
        <nav>
              Nav
          </nav>
        <div className="main-wrapper">
          <main>
            main
          </main>
          <footer>
            footer
          </footer>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>



body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    header {
      background: red;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
    }

    nav {
      background: blue;
      flex: 0 0 5%;
    }

    .main-wrapper {
      background: gray;
      display: flex;
      flex: 0 0 95%;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      main {
        background:  yellow;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
      }

      footer {
        background: darkorange;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
      }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the all the areas will fill the entire screen(without scroll bars).

I would like the header to be max-25%. Footer probably 25% (though I am still not sure if I want the footer always shown).

If the either the nav and maybe main content should have scroll bars once the content goes over a screen size.

Comment: since your html and body share 100vh, you can pass the height on to the children using `height 100%` on the `div#app` and `div.wrapper` from there you can set `height:25%` on the header and so on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sr4qykdg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not pass that `100vh` to the children and set the height as percentage as you like.

```css
body, html {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}


.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
}

header {
    background: red;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-height:25%;
 height:25%;
}

nav {
    background: blue;
    flex: 0 0 5%;
    height:75%;
}

.main-wrapper {
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 95%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height:75%;    
}

main {
    background: yellow;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height:75%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
    background: darkorange;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height:25%;
    max-height:25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    <nav>
      Nav
    </nav>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <main>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
       quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
       consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
       cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
       proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </main>
      <footer>
      footer
    </footer>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I originally tried to go down this route but for whatever reason I was having a hard time setting the % right and it did not look right.

Comment: the percentages will be weird to deal with because your footer doesn't share the same parent as your header.

Comment: Ah that might be the case, yea I am still not sure how the footer will go, if it will be outside with the header or more inside with the main area.

Comment: Grid layout is really promising for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know you don't have to convince me. I am big supporter of it, but at this time it is not a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/3pxmm0mz/1/

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  header {
    background: red;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  nav {
    background: blue;
    flex: 0 0 5%;
  }
  .main-wrapper {
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 95%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    main {
      background: yellow;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
      overflow: auto;
    }
  }
  footer {
    background: darkorange;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    <nav>
      Nav
    </nav>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
      <main>
        main
      </main>
    </div>
    <footer>
      footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the calc() to subtract a percentage or a fixed amount of pixels depending on what you go for.

Comment: Where is 200px coming from?

Comment: Also I see you have an over flow in the main area but what about the nav area?

Comment: header 100px + footer 100px = 200px

With calc() I am subtracting the header + footer height.

Comment: You can get rid of the overflow really. I tested removing it and you get a nice scroll in the body, which is neater.

Comment: I have to test that myself but I do see the nav does not handle it though. The screen will keep expanding to make room for anything I add to it.

Comment: Hmm, I am not seeing the scrolling even in the body. https://jsfiddle.net/8pjx71ty/

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using **CSS Flexbox** `flex` and `flex-wrap` to create a full-screen 2-dimensional layout, but the flexbox module is *fundamentally intended* to guide the display of specific, discrete on-page elements here and there throughout the page.

Ideally, in this setup, you can - and maybe should - be using **CSS Grid**.

This will give you all sorts of flexibility - not to mention *simplicity* - which you won't have access to, via flexbox.

**Working Example:**

```css
#app {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 25% 50% 25%;
grid-template-columns: 10% 90%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
}

header {
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
background-color: red;
}

nav {
grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
background-color: blue;
}

main {
grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
background-color:  yellow;
}

footer {
grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 3;
background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"> 
<header>Header</header>
<nav>Nav</nav>
<main>main</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I would love to use grid but with 40% of the users using the site is using IE 11, it is not possible without me writing either a fallback with either using a framework or something else.

Comment: Fair enough. I understand that rules out using CSS Grid.

Comment: Yea, I was really disappointed that as I really wanted to use it, would probably make my life alot easier, but the number was too high and the work around right now are just too much work and would increase scope too much.